# Enzyme: Test fails on BrowserHistory function

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, sinon, enzyme, sinon-chai

I am fairly new to unit tests. I am using react+redux and I have created a `NotFound` page/component and I am writings its unit test. There's an onClick event that I need to test which is failing.

**404.jsx**

```
const GenericNotFound = () => {
  const goBack = () => {
    browserHistory.goBack();
  };
  return (
    <section >
      <h1>Sorry. The requested URL is not found</h1>
      <a onClick={goBack}>Go back</a>
    </section>
  );
};
```

**Test.js**

```
 const wrapper = shallow(<GenericNotFound />);
  const browserHistory = {
    goBack: sinon.spy()
  };
  const onClick = wrapper.find('a').props().onClick;
  onClick();
  expect(browserHistory.goBack).to.have.been.called;
```

Even with this, it throws me an error `Cannot read property 'goBack' of undefined`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried as `sinon.spy(browserHistory, 'goBack')` ? Not sure abt it but give it a try

Comment: How exactly? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Instead of using `const browserHistory = {
    goBack: sinon.spy()
  };` use it as `sinon.spy(browserHistory, 'goBack')`

Comment: Nope still the same. Is it possible that this has something to do with shallow rendering not creating a full DOM? Because I believe broswerHistory needs a DOM environment?

Comment: yes, try with `mount` instead of `shallow` and spy to modify as `sinon.spy(browserHistory.prototype, 'goBack')

Comment: Can I ask why `browserHistory.prototype`?

Comment: because it is a prototype function https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/modules/InternalPropTypes.js#L15

Comment: Ah I see. I'll check with mount in a few moments. Thanks.

Comment: Did the above suggestion work?

Comment: I haven't checked but I had a little conversation to one of the contributors in enzyme, and he has confirmed that this would work with mount.

Comment: @anoop I have another issue. If you could help me out in that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38940318/enzyme-how-to-test-onsubmit-function-passed-as-prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As updated on the comments,

some changes

1. Use `mount` instead of `shallow`

`const mount = mount(<GenericNotFound />);`

2. Use `spy` as below,

`sinon.spy(browserHistory.prototype, 'goBack')`

Answer (score 2):

By following @anoop answer:

```
 it('should render an anchor tag', () => {
      sinon.spy(browserHistory, 'goBack');
      const wrapper = mount(<GenericNotFound />;
      const onClick = wrapper.find('a').props().onClick;
      onClick();
      expect(browserHistory.goBack).to.have.been.called;
      browserHistory.goBack.restore();
    });
```