# Enzyme: How to test onSubmit function passed as prop?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, redux, sinon, enzyme

I am fairly new with enzyme. I have two components under test.

**form.jsx**

```
const LoginForm = ({ style, handleSubmit }) => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Button type='submit'>
          Login
        </Button>
    </form>
  );
};

LoginForm.propTypes = {
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

I am using this component in another component as follows:

**Component.jsx**

```
export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onLogin = this.onLogin.bind(this);
  }

  onLogin(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.loginUser();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <LoginForm style={loginFormStyles} handleSubmit={this.onLogin} />      
    );
  }
}

Login.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired, //mapStateToProps
  loginUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired //mapDispatchToProps
};
```

I have written tests for `form` and they are passing.

**form-test.js**

```
 it('should have a onSubmit handler', () => {
      const props = {
        handleSubmit: () => {}
      };
      const wrapper = shallow(<LoginForm {...props} />);
      expect(_.isFunction(wrapper.props().onSubmit)).to.be.true;
    });

    it('should should call handlesubmit on form submission', () => {
      const handleSubmit = sinon.spy();
      const wrapper = shallow(<LoginForm handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />);
      wrapper.simulate('submit');
      expect(handleSubmit).to.have.been.called;
    });
```

These tests are passing. The confusing part is:

1- How do I test `onLogin` function in `Component.jsx` from `form.jsx`?

2- Vice versa, if I have to trigger `onSubmit` of `form.jsx` from `component.jsx` how would I do that?

Comment: if you are using `redux`, then i would suggest to test your actions (in this case login action). There is no major benefit on testing a click event and checking whether `redux` has done its work properly (i.e. calling action, dispatching success or failure)

Comment: Yeah I am using redux. But considering this scenario is there any way to test the parent composite component?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you can rename the `Component.jsx` to something else.

And for the test you can do something as below,

```
import Component from '../src/login';
import { stub } from 'sinon';


describe('login', () => {
  it('should call onsubmit', () => {
    const onSubmit = stub()
      .withArgs('username', 'password');
    const loginComponent = mount(<LoginForm  handleSubmit={onSubmit} /> );
    loginComponent.simulate('submit');
    expect(onSubmit.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
  });
});
```

I have not tested this but it is close to what you are looking at.

Update:
I tested this and it is working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38952021/how-to-unit-test-localstorage-using-sinon